# Selecting field by the column name

Tags: python, sql

Is there any way to get the issue of a field by its Column name.
I need something like this:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="***",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="***",                     # your username
                     passwd="***",                      # your password
                     db="***")                     # name of the data base
sql="SELECT * FROM t_table"
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute(sql)
cur.fetchall()[0]['firstName']
```

table lookslike that (sry i dont know how to create table here):

```
id |firstname|lastname

1  |Paul     |Peter
```

Have anyone an idea?

Comment: Are you referring to `Associative Arrays`? Of so it depends heavily on your `db` class implementation to support this. We would need to know which library or db engine you're using to fetch your results.

Comment: @Torxed thanks for the feedback. i added some infos

Comment: yes it works. thank u a lot :D